# Bash read file line by line and use awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have a sample.txt file in **Username:Firstname:Lastname:Telephone number** format (with several lines, and I want to create a script that converts every line into this format:

```
uid: Username
cn: LastnameFirstname
sn: Firstname
tel:Telephone number
```

So far I've managed to create the citire function that reads and prints OK only if the sample.txt has one line.

```
citire () {
uid=$1
l=$2
while read -r line
do
 name=$line
  if [ -z "$3" ]
  then
  echo -e "$uid:`echo $name|awk -F  ":" '{print $"'$l'"}'`"
  else
  l2=$3
  echo -e "$uid: `echo $name|awk -F  ":" '{print $"'$l'" $"'$l2'"}'`"
 fi
 done < /home/alexandrumohora/teste/sample.txt  
}

citire uid 1
citire cn 3 2
citire sn 2
citire tel 4
```

Can you please tell me what should I modify to make it print each record (line of the file) at a time?

Thank you!

Comment: shell is an environment from which to call tools. awk is a tool to parse/manipulate text files. You should be doing this in awk and just calling it from shell.

Comment: Oh, and never jump in and out of awk and shell like `'{print $"'$l'"}'`. It's completely unnecessary and highly error prone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you basically want *something like* this which works without `bash`:

```
 gawk 'BEGIN {FS=":"}
       { print "uid:" $1
         print " cn:" $3, $2
         print " sn:" $2
         print "tel:" $4
       }' INPUTFILE
```

**Edit:** also see the comments below my answer for proper solutions, credit goes to them!

The shortest solution might be:

```
awk -F: { printf "uid: %s\n cn: %s %s\n sn: %s\ntel: %s\n", $1, $3, $2, $3, $4 } INPUTFILE
```

Comment: +1 as you're on the right track but you've got the field numbers wrong, the "cn" needs to have $3 $2 concatenated and "sn" is $2. It doesn't need to be gawk, any awk will do, and you don't need to hard-code a space, the default OFS is good enough, and there shouldn't be leading spaces in the cn and sn lines. e.g. `print "cn:", $3 $2` or even set `OFS=": "` in BEGIN and then `print "cn", $3 $2`

Comment: You could also simplify it using `awk`s `printf` : `awk -F: { printf "uid: %s\n cn: %s %s\n sn: %s\ntel: %s\n", $1, $3, $2, $3, $4 } INPUTFILE`

Comment: @ZsoltBotykai why not edit the suggested improvements into your answer? I think it's good to put forth the best possible answer. It's more visible, loud and clear, compared with the smaller fonts in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you just want to output all records in a fixed format, or if you want the format to be configurable with the `citire` function.

Here's a simple version that outputs in a fixed format, the used in your example:

```
#!/bin/bash
data=/home/alexandrumohora/teste/sample.txt
citire() {
    while IFS=: read uid sn ln tel; do
        echo uid: $uid
        echo cn: $ln$sn
        echo sn: $sn
        echo tel:$tel
    done < "$data"
}
citire
```

And here's a more sophisticated version where `citire` takes a "recipe", making the function reusable with different formats:

```
#!/bin/bash
data=/home/alexandrumohora/teste/sample.txt
citire() {
    while IFS=: read -a fields; do
        for i; do
            case $i in
                [0-9]) printf %s "${fields[$i]}" ;;
                BR) echo ;;
                *) printf '%s: ' "$i" ;;
            esac
        done
    done < "$data"
}
citire uid 0 BR cn 2 1 BR sn 1 BR tel 3 BR
```

Explanation:

- `citire` interprets the "recipe" by looping over each item:

  - *digit i* -- print the field *i*, 0-based
  - "BR" -- print a line break
  - anything else -- use as a label: print it and a ": " after it
- Put each line in the array `fields`, using `:` as the field separator

If you don't like the recipe format, you could probably change the script to make it work like this instead:

```
citire uid 1 cn 3 2 sn 2 tel 4
```

Comment: Why would the OP want to do that instead of the trivial, robust awk solution? It would fail cryptically, by the way, if the input file ended up containing any printf formatting characters, e.g. a % sign.

Comment: @EdMorton ok, I added a robust bash solution that's equivalent to the awk solution of Zsolt. I thought the OP wanted a reusable function that takes a recipe to control the format, hence my original solution, but it looks like I was wrong, as he accepted the awk solution using fixed format.

Comment: There's still an issue. The synopsis for printf is `printf format data` so you should never write `printf data` with data that's input from a user/file because ANY formatting characters in the data will be treated as such since your putting the data where the format string is supposed to be with bizarre results. `printf "%s" data` is the right approach to solve that but at the end of the day, this just isn't a useful application to try to make work in bash - it's what awk was created to do.

Comment: @EdMorton I changed it to `printf %s "..."` which should fix that, and at the same time simplifies my previous version. But yes, `awk` would be more efficient for this.

Comment: Interesting, I'd never consider not quoting the formatting string. Wonder if there's any implications to that? Anyway, just a final suggestion might be to change `printf %s "$i: "` -> `printf '%s: ' "$i"` to keep the formatting in the formatting arg position rather than mixing it with the data in the data arg position. At the end of the day, I just can't see any reason why anyone would do this job in shell when awk is faster, more robust, concise, extensible, maintainable, etc. (i.e. better in every possible way) so it seems kinda pointless bringing it up at all but YMMV I suppose.

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton, I took your advice. I agree awk is better for this. It just so happened that I started answering in bash, and I kept going all the way without rethinking in the middle, that's all.